# Load MenuItem accelerators into FXML from a configuration file?

Tags: javafx, config, fxml, menuitem, accelerator

I am developing an application which now has an extensive Menu with Accelerators.

I am looking for a way to make it possible for the user to bind the keys for certain functions and save the key bindings for the next startup.

Is there a way to load MenuItem accelerators for an FXML file from a configuration file?

Otherwise, I would probably need to serialize a map for each MenuItem function individually.

Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: you might try to store them in a resourceBundle and then use [resource substitution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#resource_resolution) to look them up

Comment: @kleopatra I did not have the time to try this out, but it seems as if this would be a nice solution. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [KeyCombination.getName()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#getName()) to get a `String` representation of a `MenuItem` accelerator and [KeyCombination.keyCombination(String)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#keyCombination(java.lang.String)) to create  a `MenuItem` accelerator from a `String` representation. See example:

```
KeyCombination accelerator =  new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.D, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Click me");
menuItem.setAccelerator(accelerator);

...

//save accelerator to the config file
String accString = menuItem.getAccelerator().getName();
saveAcceleratorToConfig(accString); // save string to file

...

//load accelerator from the config file
String accString = loadAcceleratorFromConfig(); //load string from file
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(accString));
```